# Variance of a combination of random vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, statistics, linear-transformations, matrix-calculus

I was looking at the proof for optimal weighting matrix when using GMM (slide 35 [here](http://www.biostat.jhsph.edu/bstcourse/bio771/sec9.pdf))
At one point, they take the variance of both sides of following expression (where Z is a random vector)

$A_1Z = A_0Z + (A_1-A_0)Z$

And get the following:

$var(A_1 Z) =var( A_0Z) + var((A_1-A_0)Z) + A_0  var(Z)(A_1'-A_0') + (A_1-A_0)Var(Z)A_0'$

which evalates to $var( A_0Z) + var((A_1-A_0)Z)$

After a lot of thinking, I don't seem to get how the term $var(Z)(A_1'-A_0') + (A_1-A_0)Var(Z)A_0'$ shows up. Can anyone help please, what part of the linear algebra class I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case the random vector $Z$ has zero mean. So your calculation simplifies to $\operatorname{Var}(X+Y)$ where $X:=A_0 Z$ and $Y:=(A_1-A_0)Z$ are mean-zero random vectors. Since $X+Y$ will also have mean zero, its variance is $\operatorname{Var}(X+Y)=E(X+Y)(X+Y)'$, which equals
$$
E(XX' + YY' +XY' + YX')=\operatorname{Var}(X)+\operatorname{Var}(Y)+E(XY')+E(YX'),
$$
where the final two terms are
$$E(XY')=E\left(A_0Z[(A_1-A_0)Z]'\right)=A_0E(ZZ')(A_1'-A_0')$$
and
$$E(YX')=E\left([(A_1-A_0)Z](A_0Z)'\right)=(A_1-A_0)E(ZZ')A_0'.$$
To finish off, observe that $E(ZZ')=\operatorname{Var}(Z)$ since $Z$ has zero mean.

Comment: All is clear now, thanks a lot!